# <a href> requires http://www. or extends current URL

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

When I am using a `<a href="examplesite.org" target="_blank">` if I click the link I am taken to currentsite/examplesite.org.

If I then change this to `<a href="http://www.examplesite.org" target="_blank">` I am taken to the correct site.

As these links are data driven (pulled from a URLs table in my Database) I would rather not have to either:

1. Hardcode 'http://www' into my html to get around it
2. Include this in every url in my table, as some may not require it. (internal urls)

Any advice?

Comment: You can modify them with your server side code. Simply check whether or not they're internal links after pulling them from the database and modify as necessary.

Comment: How are the links being generated? I assume that it's PHP or ASP.NET or something similar.

Comment: The only definitive way to know that something is an external link however would be to add a boolean field to my data table and mark them on a case by case basis. Is there a way to force the "a href" to take all urls as literal and not try to append to the existing URL

Comment: I am using Django Framework FYI @jsve

Comment: You could add attribute `data-type='absolute'` and write little js script to handle link click. This way you can control which links are relative and which are absolute.

Comment: So the easiest way to force it into literals is to append // to the front?

Comment: @Malekai: I think you mean “absolute” rather than “literals”, but yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you could prepend `//` to each URL in your HTML:

```
<a href="//examplesite.org" target="_blank">
```

This will make the link relative to the current page’s protocol (i.e. http or https), but will otherwise make the `href` value be treated as a domain name.

Of course, this assumes that the link’s `href` value will always be intended as a domain. It’s difficult to differentiate an `href` intended as a domain (e.g. examplesite.org) from one intended as a relative page link on your site (e.g. examplepage.html), especially now that [top-level domains have gone insane](https://iwantmyname.com/domains/new-gtld-domain-extensions).